# Query in HTML where with and without using the tag <thead></thead> displaying different outputs

Tags: html, css

I have two cases where the HTML script displaying differently with and without using `<thead></thead>` tag.

SCENARIO 1 : (With `<thead></thead>` tag)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>

        <head>
              <title>HTML PAGE</title>
        </head>

        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "TEST_CSS.CSS"> <!--Linking our .CSS sheet-->

        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <caption>EXAMPLE TABLE</caption>
                <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th colspan = "2">NAME</th> 
                         <th>AGE</th>
                         <th>SEX</th>
                     </tr>
                     </thead>
                         <tr>
                             <td>REBEL RIDER</td>
                             <td>RR</td>
                             <td>5</td> 
                             <td>MALE</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>IGR</td>
                             <td>4:20R</td>
                             <td>11</td>
                             <td>MALE</td>
                         </tr>

                     <tr>
                     <td colspan = "4">END OF THE TABLE</td>
                     <tr/>

            </table>
        </body>
```

SCENARIO 2: (Without `<thead></thead>`)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>

        <head>
              <title>HTML PAGE</title>
        </head>

        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "TEST_CSS.CSS"> <!--Linking our .CSS sheet-->

        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <caption>EXAMPLE TABLE</caption>

                         <tr>
                             <th colspan = "2">NAME</th> 
                             <th>AGE</th>
                             <th>SEX</th>
                         </tr>                      
                         <tr>
                             <td>REBEL RIDER</td>
                             <td>RR</td>
                             <td>5</td> 
                             <td>MALE</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td>IGR</td>
                             <td>4:20R</td>
                             <td>11</td>
                             <td>MALE</td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                         <td colspan = "4">END OF THE TABLE</td>
                         <tr/>

            </table>
        </body>
```

I am using the common CSS for above 2 scenarios to style the every 2nd row as below.

```
tr:nth-child(2n)
{
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

I am getting a different output for the above 2 scenarios.

OUTPUT(Scenario 1)

[image]

OUTPUT(Scenario 2)

[image]

My question is what role does `<thead></thead>` play in displaying the output differently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have a `<thead>` you have a single `odd` row inside it, and other 3 *siblings* rows as children of the table - actually of the *tbody* -  (`odd`, `even`, `odd`)

Without `thead` all rows are siblings so you have `odd`, `even`, `odd`, `even`.

In other words: a row is odd or even relatively to its immediate parent (or its siblings).

From MDN:

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of **siblings**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but using `<div>` instead of `<thead>` is not bringing the same effect as with and without using `<thead>`. What is the difference between them..?

Comment: I mean as we style for `tr` as `tr:nth-child(2n)` doesn't this apply for all the `tr`..?

Comment: that rule is applied both for table and thead so on thead that row is ODD. and the next row relatively to its parent is also ODD

Comment: One more question, bit out of the context - I've used <div> instead of <thead>. It produced the same results with and without using <div>. So the <tr> inside the <div> is not considered as its child element..?

Comment: A `<div>` is not a valid element as a direct child of a `<table>` or `<tbody>`. So it's just ignored, I suppose (and the browser pretends it doesn't exist).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`tr:nth-child(2n)` indicates that you want the 2nd, 4th, ... TRs with a common parent to have a gray background.

In the first (with thead) table, you have split the TRs into two distinct sibling groups, the first with one child, and the second with three. The thead only has one TR child, so its TR isn't gray. The other 3 TRs have the table as their parent, and so the 2nd one is gray.

In the second table (without thead), the table has four children, and the 2nd and 4th TRs have gray backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But since we style for `tr` as `tr:nth-child(2n)` doesn't this apply for all the `tr`..?

Comment: I've updated my answer. nth-child means nth child with the same parent.

Comment: One more question, bit out of the context - I've used `<div>` instead of `<thead>`. It produced the same results with and without using <div>. So the <tr> inside the <div> is not considered as its child element..?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.